# Issue with accents or Special characters in Json (Abap)

Tags: web-services, http, abap

I am consuming a HTTP service from abap.
The service returns me a json with the following data:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Ã©xito",
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "584e9469df829275019c4a74",
      "nombre": "COCHAMÃ“",
      "Ãštil": "Si",
      "email": "supervisor@demo.com",
      "Sms NÃºmero de telÃ©fono": "981363931",
      "Llamar al telÃ©fono": "26944444",
      "Radio de bÃºsquedaPedido PÃºblico(Km) 1": 3,
      "Radio de bÃºsquedaPedido PÃºblico(Km) 2": 3,
      "Radio de bÃºsquedaPedido PÃºblico(Km) 3": 3,
      "Tiempo de Descarga masa(min)": 10,
      "Radio de bÃºsquedaPedido Privado(Km)": 1,
      "Cola de Pedidos(n)": 6,
      "Tiempo de Esperapara Asignar pedidos(Sgds)": 45,
      "Hora de finalizaciÃ³n": "21:00"
        }
  ]
}
```

The code:

```
 Call method cl_http_client=>create_by_url
     Exporting
      url                = lv_url
     Importing
      client             = Data(lcl_client)
     Exceptions
      argument_not_found = 1
      plugin_not_active  = 2
      internal_error     = 3
      Others             = 4.
     If sy-subrc Ne 0.
      Raise urlexception.
     Else.
      Data(lcl_request) = lcl_client->request.
      lcl_client->request->set_method( if_http_request=>co_request_method_post ).
      lcl_request->set_form_field( name = Parametro1 value = lv_mail ).
      lcl_request->set_form_field( name = Parametro2 value = lv_password ).
      If idcomuna Is Not Initial.
       lv_comunasap = idcomuna.
       lcl_request->set_form_field( name = Parametro3 value = lv_comunasap ).
      Endif.
      If idcomunagc Is Not Initial.
       lv_comunamongo = idcomunagc.
       lcl_request->set_form_field( name = Parametro4 value = lv_comunamongo ).
      Endif.

      cl_http_utility=>set_request_uri(  request = lcl_request
                                            uri  = lv_url ).
      Call method lcl_client->send
       Exceptions
        http_communication_failure = 1
        http_invalid_state         = 2
        http_processing_failed     = 3
        http_invalid_timeout       = 4
        Others                     = 5.
        If sy-subrc Ne 0.
         Raise sendexception.
        Else.
         Call method lcl_client->receive
          Exceptions
           http_communication_failure = 1
           http_invalid_state         = 2
           http_processing_failed     = 3
          Others                      = 4.
          If sy-subrc <> 0.
          Else.
           lcl_client->response->get_status( Importing code = Data(lv_code) reason = Data(lv_reason) ).
           Data(lv_respuesta) = lcl_client->response->get_cdata( ).
```

- Originally the json should come with accents(Spanish names).
- The Ã©, Ãº are one of the strange characters that it should be letter with accent.
  How to get the json full data with accents in my ABAP program?

Comment: It does not seem like an issue at all. Where are you displaying this json conent? It looks like the response is encoded in UTF-8 an the only issue you have you are displaying it in a viewer that interprets it as another encoding (ISO-8859-1?).

Comment: I dont need to display this data at all, i just need to obtain some data and insert them in database.

Comment: Well, you needed to display the data in order to state that something is wrong with it and to write this post, didn't you? There is nothing wrong with the data, you just need to decode it properly according to its encoding.

Comment: Is the ABAP system a unicode system or not? (Check System > Status for this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever it's output on a display or in a variable, @Jagger is right, the response is returned in UTF-8. As you use GET_CDATA (get characters), I think that SAP takes the explicit `charset` given in the response header (`Content-Type: text/json;charset=utf-8`), and so it should be converted correctly. If it's not, then maybe the charset is missing in the header.

So, if it's not given, then do the conversion yourself, the same way as for any other UTF-8:

First of all, use GET_DATA (not GET_CDATA) to read it as a string of bytes, then convert it into a string of characters by using the method CONVERT_FROM (codepage = `utf-8`) of the class CL_ABAP_CODEPAGE.